# Jquery drop down option values not changing in button, button link is repeating

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I'm having trouble figuring out my code. When a user selects a corporation from the drop down, the name, phone number, email and cc all appear correctly and change when a different option is selected. I want to incorporate a button for a "mailto:"" link using the values from email and cc.

I created variables for the href link.
Now when I select an option, I want it to display a button for emailing the individual; it currently shows three "Email Us" links (my three corporation options).

Then when I click the button it shows only one cc address not two, and my subject line gets cut off or doesn't get added.

Also the button values don't change from the first option selected. So if I change the the option selected, the name and phone changes but not the variables for email and cc in the link.

[Here is my Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/WrQO7WNQc7YkcWehsKyf?p=preview%22)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("select").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'main.xml',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'xml',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        retrieveXml(data);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
      }
    });
  });
});

var retrieveXml = function(data) {
  $(data).find('business').each(function() {
    var corpName = $(this).find('business-name').text();

    // Setup Variables
    var corpData = {
      name: ($('name', data).text()),
      phone: ($('phone', data).text()),
      email: ($('email', data).text()),
      businessname: ($('business-name', data).text())
    };

    var webOption = $('select#corps option:selected').val();
    var businessName = $('business-name', data).text();

    $(data).find('business').each(function(index, item) {

      var corpName = $(this).find('business-name').text();
      if (webOption == corpName) {
        $("#name").html($(this).find('manager > name').text());
        $("#phone").html($(this).find('manager > phone').text());
        $("#email").html($(this).find('manager > email').text());
        //$("#email").html($(this).find('manager > email').text());
        //$("#cced").html($(this).find('manager> cced').text());

        //NEW CODE
        $("#btn").addClass("button-color");
        var em = $(this).find('manager > email').html();
        var cced = $(this).find('manager > cced').html();
        var subject = "&subject=";
        var button = "Email Us";
        var cc = "?cc=";
        var bcc = "&bcc=execontact@gmail.com"
        var subMessage = "Contact a manager";
        $("#btn").append("<a href=mailto:" + em + cc + cced + bcc + subject + subMessage + " >" + button + "</a>");
        return false;
      }
    });


  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add quotemark before mailto:

```
$( "#btn" ).html('<a href="mailto:' + em + cc + cced + bcc + subject + subMessage + '">' + button + '</a>');
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the mail to issue. 
Now the only issue is the duplicate "Email Us" links. I just need to get the "Email us" link to show once instead of three times

Comment: and my data doesn't change when a different option is selected

Comment: I changed append to html and it fixed the problem,